# PHP - how to send RAW post fields while using POST method?

Tags: php, json, curl

Using PHP, Curl (ZF2), I need to submit via POST method RAW field values to third party API.

When i send it as following, it does not work, SERVER refuse to accept:

```
$ss = array(
    'id'=> array('a1','b2')
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ss); // FAIL
```

or

```
$ss = array(
    'id'=> 'a1,b2'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ss); // FAIL
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'id=a1,b2'); // FAIL
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'&id=a1,b2'); // FAIL
```

But when i manually send it as following, SERVER accepts it, and it works:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'{
  "id": [
    "a1",
    "b2"
  ]
}');
```

How do i submit array `$ss` in that format which is getting accepted?

Comment: It looks like the server is expecting JSON... in which case, what about `json_encode`?

Comment: json_encode works now. Thanks